# What is the way to pass an argument from one winform to another and using that argument to display a rdlc report in C#

Tags: database, datatable, dataset, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I had created a Query Report(rdlc) in Visual Studio 2015, I had made one form and bind that report to a reportviwer control,I am using that report for displaying bill and report is displayed by getting an argument called `invoice_id` from an another form.
But when i use this code nothing is displayed in the report

```
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.bill_data.DataTable1,invoice_id);

this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Here,`invoice_id` is the parameter which is generated from a another form and passed to the current form.
All the data first inserted into the database and this report will fetch the data directly from database.

Answer (score 0):

I had Got answer for this question after a help of one my friend,
You can create your own Datatable with the help of datareader which will fetch data from database directly using query

Let's have a look on my code.

```
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = '..\\..\\inventory.accdb'");
        cn.Open();
        string str = "SELECT tbl_customers.customer_name, tbl_customers.address, tbl_customers.mobile, tbl_customers.pincode, tbl_city.city_name, tbl_product.product_name, tbl_sales.quantity, tbl_sales.invoice_time, "
                     + "tbl_sales.invoice_date, tbl_sales.invoice_id, tbl_sales.price, tbl_product.id, tbl_sales.per, ledger.amount, ledger.tax " 
                        + "FROM ((((tbl_customers INNER JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_customers.id = tbl_sales.cust_id) INNER JOIN tbl_city ON tbl_customers.city_id = tbl_city.ID) INNER JOIN "
                      + "tbl_product ON tbl_sales.productid = tbl_product.id) INNER JOIN ledger ON tbl_sales.invoice_id = ledger.invoice_id) WHERE(tbl_sales.invoice_id = '"+"3"+"')";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, cn);
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        ReportDataSource Mynew = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (DataTable)dt);

        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Mynew);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I Hope this is helpfull